# How do I choose what I want field in fosuserbundle？

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I use fosuserbundle, I want to write the entity, but when I inherited User, I found that I can't choose what you want to field. My data in the table must have a baseUser all fields. I'm so depressed

Answer (score 0):

Don't be depressed about it, it's just programming! It sounds like you're not happy about inheriting all the fields from the base User entity? If you really don't like it then you don't need to use FOSUserBundle. The bundle handles a lot of things for you, but to make all these possible it needs all those fields.